# Python Parallel through 3 nested loops in 3D space

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to update a 3D tensor in python where I am looping through all of the locations and updating each position independently based off of other values.  The code is going through 3D space an updating one set of properties of that space based on another set of properties.

I am trying to find an efficient way to run it in parallel on processor threads or GPU.  I have tried joblib from Parallel and multiprocessing, but both have me building a list of every possible combination of inputs from the nested loops into a single variable, running that in parallel, and then reconstructing a tensor.  It has been the only way around the GIL I have found, but it is not very efficient, and seems to not give the same results as serial.

Anyone have advice on how to do this efficiently?

Sample simplified code how I have it working in Series:

```
import numpy as np

l = 10
w = 10
h = 10


def UpdateMat1(x, y, z):
    Mat1[x, y, z] = Mat2[x, y, z] + 2 * y


def UpdateMat2(x, y, z):
    Mat2[x, y, z] = Mat1[x, y, z] * 3


Mat = range(l * w * h)

Mat1 = np.reshape(Mat, (l, w, h))
Mat2 = np.ones((l, w, h))

for t in range(10):

    for x in range(10):
        for y in range(10):
            for z in range(10):
                UpdateMat1(x, y, z)

    for x in range(10):
        for y in range(10):
            for z in range(10):
                UpdateMat2(x, y, z)

    Mat2 += t
```

I have tried creating a list of all (x,y,z) combinations, and using that as a variable for parallel, and then depacking there result, it was not efficient, and the results did not match series.

Comment: It's unclear. Does your example show the real pattern of updating tensors? I guess not. If it is, why not split a tensor into matrices along the y index?

Comment: The functions are notional.  The actual functions are roughly 400 lines long with lots of logic, but mostly simple math.

Comment: I mean you need to provide the pattern of updating tensors, so we can evaluate whether it can be parallelized.

Comment: There's no magic tool that automatically converts you code to parallelized one. Anyway see [Parallel Programming with numpy and scipy](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ParallelProgramming.html) and [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/).

Comment: @relent95 thank you for the links.  I have not tried numba.  My attempts with joblib have actually slowed down the code as each thread is always waiting for the tensors.

Comment: The code that I am working on is here on my github [link] (http://127.0.0.1:8888/notebooks/Code/3D_EFIT/OtherCode/efit3D-Copy1.ipynb) is is a simulation of sound and mechanical waves in solid medium.  The loop section where I have been experimenting with joblib is in In[11]

Comment: That URL is only accessible on your computer. Try something like Github Gist if you don't want to post in SO.

Comment: Wrong link, was the jupyter server, not the github version:  github [link] (https://github.com/danchendrickson/3D_EFIT/blob/main/OtherCode/efit3D-Copy1.ipynb

Comment: You are solving PDE, right? What about vectorizing calculations using [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), [einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), [convolve](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html), etc. Also there are packages like [FiPy](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/). If you want reuse existing non-vectorized implementation, your best bet will be Numba.

Comment: No PDEs in this code.  I will try working with numba.  Thank you for your advice.